# Unity Rigidbody2D Velocity Sudden Freeze

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I wrote a script in C# for Character Movement using Rigidbody2D velocity.However,sometimes when I try to move,my character moves then suddenly freezes and won't go forward.Only backwards.I checked the colliders and they are all equal and snapped.I tried even AddForce but it still freezes.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField]
float speed = 5;
[SerializeField]
float jumpForce = 500;
[SerializeField]
LayerMask whatisground;
[SerializeField]
bool isGrounded = false;
Transform groundCheck;

private Rigidbody2D rb2d;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rb2d = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    groundCheck = gameObject.transform.GetChild (0);
}

void FixedUpdate(){
    float hor = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    rb2d.AddForce (new Vector2 (hor * speed,0));

    //rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(hor*speed,rb2d.velocity.y);
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (groundCheck.position, 0.15F);
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Comment: Did you tried specify forcemode? `rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(hor * speed, 0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);`

Comment: No,but I don't think it really matters.

Answer (score 0):

Does your character walk from a collider to another?
If that's the case, check if the intersection between the colliders in holding your character back.

Comment: Make sure that the colliders going forward aren't higher than the ones before it. It could make it so that the character keeps walking against the next collider.

Comment: They are all the same height.I know for sure since I'm using prefabs